# How to merge two CNN that are trained over different data stream?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to merge two CNNs that are trained over the different dataset. I have take two sequential models and merged them. But when using customized fit_generato, validation loss is not converging. How will I pass generators of different datasets?

```
input1_1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(129,129,3))
x1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size = (3,3), filters = 32, 
activation='PReLU')(input1_1)

x3 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x1)
x4 = keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size = (5,5), filters = 64, 
activation='relu')(x3)
x5 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x4)
x6 = keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size = (7,7), filters = 128, 
activation='relu')(x5)
d1_1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x6)
br1_1= keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(d1_1)
br1_1 = keras.layers.Flatten()(br1_1)


input2_2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(129,129,3))
x1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size = (3,3), filters = 32, 
activation='PReLU')(input2_2)

x3 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x1)
x4 = keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size = (5,5), filters = 64, 
activation='relu')(x3)
x5 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x4)
x6 = keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size = (7,7), filters = 128, 
activation='relu')(x5)
d2_2 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x6)
br2_2= keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)(d2_2)
br2_2 = keras.layers.Flatten()(br2_2)

added1_1 = keras.layers.concatenate([br1_1, br2_2], axis=1)
d2_3 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(added1_1)
# d2_4 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(d2_3)
out1_1 = keras.layers.Dense(159,activation='softmax',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
            activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01))(d2_3)
# model=keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size= (4,4), filters=10, activation='relu')(out)
modal1_1 = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1_1,input2_2], outputs=out1_1)
modal1_1.summary()

modal1_1.compile(##args)
modal1_1.fit_genrator(????)
```

what arguments should be passed in fit_generator that will combine two generators other than zip. i have performed some experiments using Zip but it is not solving the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It is really unclear what you are trying to do. Why did you merge your layers if you don't use them later? 
 I think what you need is this:

```
layer = concatenate ([face, sig])
model = Model (inputs = [inputs], outputs=[layer])
```

Comment: Actually, i want to make such model that will take two different images as input and train as one model.

Comment: yes i forgot to mention that one line where i added that merged to final model.  i have edited the question please suggest the way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a short example.

```
input_face = Input(shape=(148, 148, 3))
input_sig = Input(shape=(148, 148, 3))

face = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3))(input_face)
face = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3))(face)
face = Flatten()(face)

sig = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3))(input_sig)
sig = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3))(sig)
sig = Flatten()(sig)

output = concatenate([sig, face])
output = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(output)
model = Model(inputs=[input_face, input_sig], outputs=[output])
model.compile(#args)
model.fit([np.array, np.array])
```

So here input data should be a list of two numpy array containing images

Comment: Obviously, just pass list of two generators

Comment: I get an error when i pass two fit_generator. i have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
 model.fit_generator([face_gen, sig_gen], arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your generator so that it will produce output like this ([sig, face], target), since fit_generator takes only one generator.

Comment: how can i do that ? can you please help me in that?